# Python point and guessing system

Tags: python, system, point

What would be a good way to do this system:

User has a maximum of 2 chances to answer the question.
There is 4 questions in total.
If the user guesses the answer on the 1st try, they get 2 points.
If the user guesses the answer on the 2nd try, they get 1 point. 
If the user doesn't get the answer within the 2 chances, they get 0 points for that question and move on to the next. 
And then after all four questions, it lists the mark they got /8. (4 questions, 2 points per question)

I tried this:

```
print("Question number one:")                                      #Question two
print("How many Call of Duty games are there?")
print("a) 4")
print("b) 6")
print("c) 2")
print("d) 8") 
question = int(input("Your answer: "))
maxGuesses = 2
guessesTaken = 0
points = 0
if question == 8:
    print("You are correct! You guessed the answer on the first try!")
    points = points + maxGuesses-guessesTaken
    print("You scored", (maxGuesses-guessesTaken), "points!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
    print("You have", (maxGuesses-guessesTaken-1), "guess remaining!")
    answer = int(input("Your answer: "))
    if answer == 8:
        print("You are correct!")
        points = points + maxGuesses-guessesTaken
        print("You scored", (maxGuesses-guessesTaken-1), "points!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print("Next question!")
```

But that wouldn't work because if the user guessed the answer wrong the first try and got it right the 2nd try, it would still count it as 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `guessesTaken` after they guess by doing `guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1`, or a shorter way would be to do `guessesTaken += 1`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where would I insert that?

Comment: Dude, this looks like homework - you are supposed to apply yourself. Try something.

Comment: this is definitely homework - see `#Question two` and "(4 questions, 2 points per question)" in the question. Sorry - ask your teacher!

Comment: This is actually an assignment, however, if I don't understand something and this is due the next day who am I supposed to ask?